# Convert ASCII string to corresponding sentence and back

Tags: java, ascii

I'm trying to convert a string of ASCII numbers to their corresponding string values.

For instance how can I convert a string such as `'This is good'` to a string of ASCII numbers or convert a string `84114117116104326510811997121115328710511011532` to the corresponding sentence?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: `public static char ASCIIToChar(final int ascii){
            return (char)ascii;
    }`  Just this but this converts to only one character

Answer (score 1):

84114117116104326510811997121115328710511011532 **can't** be converted back, because : 
How should it be read ? 8 and 41 or 84 and 1 ? You need separators.
And you will have to use charAt() :

```
String s="This is good";
String ascii="";
String separator=":";
for (int i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
     int c=s.charAt(i);
     ascii+=Integer.toString(c);
     if (i < s.length-1) {
         ascii+=separator;
     }
}
//Converting it back : 
String[] characters=ascii.split(separator);
String converted_back="";
for (String string:characters) {
     converted_back+=new String(new char[]{(char)Integer.parseInt(string)});
}
```

Feel free to ask any question. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

From String to int it is easy you can use :

```
String str = "This is good";
String number = "";
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    number += (int) c;
}
```

But from `int` to `String` this is not possible, because you don't have any logic how you get cut your string to get the correspondence values, for example :

> `84114` this can be -> can be Th T(84) and h(114) or `TVT` T(84) + VT(11) and 4( ) empty.

[image: http://onlinecalculators.brainmeasures.com/Conversions/StringtoAsciiCalculator.aspx]

[Source](http://onlinecalculators.brainmeasures.com/Conversions/StringtoAsciiCalculator.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   string  encode="84114117116104326510811997121115328710511011532";
        string str = encode;
        int l=0;
        l=str.length();

        string decode1="";
        //l--;

        int i=0
        char c;
        while(i<=l){

            c=str[i];

            if( c=='3'||c=='4'||c=='5'||c=='6'||c=='7'||c=='8'||c=='9'){
                    i++;
                char c1=str[i];
                string y;
                y.push_back(c);
                y.push_back(c1);
                int num=stoi(y);

                char c3=num;

                decode1.push_back(c3);

                i++;

            }

            if(c=='1'){
               i++;
                char c1=str[i];
                i++;
                char c2=str[i];
                string y;
                y.push_back(c);
                y.push_back(c1);
                y.push_back(c2);
                int num=stoi(y);
                char c3=num;
                decode1.push_back(c3);

               i--;


            }
            cout<<decode1;
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Others will find it hard to study your code.